# plot histogram from pandas dataframe using the list values in (column, row) pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I want to make a histogram plot (both, overlapped and non-overlayed between chromosomes) from `pandas Dataframe` with following columns.

```
my_cols = ['chrom', 'len_PIs']
chrom = pd.Series(['chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3'])
len_of_PIs = pd.Series([[np.random.randint(15, 59, 86)],
                    [np.random.randint(18, 55, 92)],
                    [np.random.randint(25, 61, 98)]])

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'chrom': chrom,
                'len_PIs': len_of_PIs},
                 columns=my_cols)

print('\nhere is df5')
print(df5)
print(type(df5))
print(type(df5['len_PIs']))

here is df5
  chrom                                            len_PIs
0  chr1  [[18, 45, 33, 58, 48, 47, 45, 39, 42, 46, 48, ...
1  chr2  [[45, 32, 49, 46, 53, 40, 46, 35, 44, 24, 51, ...
2  chr3  [[53, 32, 35, 35, 49, 31, 57, 42, 46, 49, 49, ...
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

So, now I want to make the histogram for each `chrom` usig the `len_PIs` value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('histogram_byChr.png', 'w'):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.subplot()
    plt.xlabel('chrom')
    plt.ylabel('len_PIs')
    fig.suptitle('length of PIs distribution for each chromosome')

    # these two method (below) are close but don't work

    plt.plot(my_df.groupby('chrom')['len_PIs'])
    # error message which doesn't make sense to me
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'chr3'

    my_df.groupby('chrom').plot.hist(alpha=0.5)
    # Error message
    TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Comment: Your example code produces only NaNs. Can you look at it again?

Comment: I just updated the code. I mistyped `len_PIs`, but that wasn't the issue in my original code. I retried to see other typos and don't see any issue. Let me know if see other issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data seems rather unusually stored in the dataframe. Yet you may just iterate over it and plot the respective histograms.

```
## Plot all three histograms in a single plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, data in my_df.iterrows():
    ax.hist(data["len_PIs"], label=data['chrom'], alpha=.5)
ax.legend()
plt.show()

## Plot each histogram in its own subplot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(my_df), sharex=True)
for i, data in my_df.iterrows():
    axes[i].hist(data["len_PIs"], label=data['chrom'], alpha=.5)
    axes[i].legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The reason being unusual is that the lengths of `len_PIs` is not same across `chrom`. I could have put `chr1` ... as columns but thought unequal length would complicate histogram plotting. Thanks much though !

Comment: @everestial007 it doesn't, if you do it for example, as I've done using stack.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a bit of data reshaping here. Explode your list column into separate columns -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        pd.DataFrame(df.len_PIs.tolist())[0].tolist(), index=df.chrom
)

df    
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ...     88    89    90    91  \
chrom                                          ...                            
chr1   58  15  55  53  40  25  49  38  47  34  ...    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
chr2   37  42  24  38  24  46  24  20  46  46  ...   43.0  54.0  44.0  22.0   
chr3   35  37  58  57  58  51  60  50  49  43  ...   37.0  32.0  41.0  54.0   

         92    93    94    95    96    97  
chrom                                      
chr1    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
chr2    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
chr3   25.0  48.0  40.0  35.0  28.0  28.0
```

Next, `stack` your data horizontally. Finally, call `groupby` + `plot`.

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).plot.hist(alpha=0.5, legend=True);
plt.show()
```

[image]